# Parsing spaces and returns

Tags: parsing, vbscript

I have arrived at the below code to read the file name and contents of *.txt files within a specified folder. My current issue is that it seems to interpret returns as spaces within the read contents instead of inserting a return. I would also like to be able to parse and replace tabs in the txt file with a number of spaces to simulate a "tab". How may I achieve this?

```
<Html>
<Head>

    <Title>Installer</Title>

<Script Language="VBScript" Type="Text/VBScript">

'--  Resize & move app to center

       Sub SetWindow( WidthX,HeightY )
          Self.ResizeTo WidthX, HeightY
          Self.MoveTo (screen.Width - WidthX)/2, (screen.Height - HeightY)/2
       End Sub

'--  Call Window resize Sub
       SetWindow 800, 600

</Script>

<Hta:Application    Id="Installer"  ApplicationName="Installer"     Version="0.1"

    SingleInstance="Yes"
          Icon="image/appIcon.ico" 
          Caption="No"
          Border="None"
          InnerBorder="No"
          ContextMenu="No"
          SysMenu="Yes"
          Scroll="No"
          Selection="No"

/>
</Head>
<Body>

<Script Language="VBScript" Type="Text/VBScript">

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "Notes\"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
   For Each objFile in colFiles
   If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "TXT" Then

Files = objStartFolder & objFile.name
Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Files, 1)

    document.write Left(objFile.name, Len(objFile.name)-4) & "<br>"

    document.write objReadFile.ReadAll & "<br><br>"
objReadFile.Close

else
    document.write ="File was empty"

End If
Next

</Script>

</Body>
</Html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML does not handle the CRLF at the end of the lines in the way you expect.

You can replace all line ends with `<br>` tags

```
document.write Replace(objReadFile.ReadAll, vbCRLF, "<br>") & "<br><br>"
```

Or you can place the file contents inside `<pre>` tags

```
document.write "<pre>" & objReadFile.ReadAll & "</pre><br><br>"
```

Maybe the second option will better fit your problem as you also want to replace tabs with spaces

```
document.write "<pre>" & replace(objReadFile.ReadAll, vbTab, "  ") & "</pre><br><br>"
```

Comment: I can't remember since it's been that long since I've worked with forms, but will text areas respect this? As in the proper formatting of the file? If I choose to output the resulting string into it that is?

I also presume this code will work: `document.write Replace(objReadFile.ReadAll, vbCRLF, "<br>", vbTab, "  ")`

Comment: Kind of achieved it with this: `repReturn = Replace(objReadFile.ReadAll, vbCRLF, "<br>")
    repTab = Replace(repReturn, vbTab, "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;")
    document.write repTab & "<br><br>"` But I am sure it could be condensed. Just used what little I know to achieve it. Unfortunately, the HTA doesn't respect multiple non breaking spaces...So I am unsure of how to achieve the tab "effect"

Comment: After further consideration, I've decided to drop the tab replace from the code, as it doesn't really seem all that beneficial considering this is going to be a templating engine. More or less designed to allow a user to make a txt file template, with replacable tags within it, such as [name], [address] etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the modified code to get the desired outcome I wanted, for those who want it in plain code format:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "Notes\"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
   For Each objFile in colFiles
   If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "TXT" Then

        Files = objStartFolder & objFile.name
        Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Files, 1)

        strExt = Left(objFile.name, Len(objFile.name)-4)
        strNote = Replace(objReadFile.ReadAll, vbCRLF, "<br>")

    objReadFile.Close

        document.write strExt & "<br><br>"
        document.write strNote & "<br><br>"

    else
    document.write ="File was empty"

    End If
Next
```

Comment: I will post this as a seperate question if need be, but it's kinda relating to this. I would like to take the loop here that obtains the file name (strExt) and that gets the file contents (strNote) and build them into seperate dynamic arrays that I can use to output later in the file. Would anyone be able to supply an additional answer to this effect with the code I have placed above?